# Правильное употребление предлога о

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

*Ряд авторов занимает позицию о неприменении этого метода.*

Грамотна ли фраза?

Answer (score 1):

Нет. 
Ближайший грамматически правильный вариант - "Ряд авторов занимает позицию неприменения этого метода". Ну или уж "выступает за неприменение". Последнее лучше всего стилистически.

Comment: "за неприменение" стилистически лучше? Почему не "против применения"?

Comment: @Qwertiy "против применения" (и вообще без "позиции"), разумеется, лучше. Но я не навязываю свою стилистическое чувство, если меня о том не спрашивают. Отвечаю именно на тот вопрос, который задан. Впрочем, это такой давний вопрос... Сейчас уж и не вспомнишь, о чем думалось на заре существования ресурса

Answer (score 0):

О - это предлог. Предложение построено неправильно:  слово "позиция" не может управлять предложным падежом.

Comment: 1. Такое особое, ущербное, слабое, что управлять не может? 2. То, что о предлог, автор вопроса, похоже, знает.

Comment: Непонятна суть последнего комментария. Если за словом "позиция" идет существительное, то между ними должна быть связь по типу управления: позиция (кого? чего?) <существительное в родительном падеже> – М_Г 1